# Sudoku checker issues with Python

Tags: python, sudoku

I'm trying to create a sudoku checker in Python. I found a version here in another thread, but it does not work properly. I wonder what is the issue?
I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omistaja\Downloads\sudoku_checker_template.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Omistaja\Downloads\sudoku_checker_template.py", line 63, in main
    is_valid = check_sudoku_grid(grid)
  File "C:\Users\Omistaja\Downloads\sudoku_checker_template.py", line 20, in check_sudoku_grid
    if grid[row][col] < 1 or type(grid[row][col]) is not type(1):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Anyway, below is the whole thing. Only the check_sudoku_grid should be modified, the rest should work. Thanks for your help!

```
from grids import GRID_NAMES, GRID_RETURNS, GRIDS, GRIDS_BIG, GRIDS_SMALL

GRID_SIZE = 9 # Length of one side of the sudoku
SUBGRID_SIZE = 3 # Length of one side of a cell of the sudoku

def check_sudoku_grid(grid):
    """
    Parameter : GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE two-dimensional list
    Return value : Boolean (True/False)
    
    Checks whether a sudoku grid is valid 
    ie. doesn't contain any duplicates (besides None)
    in any row, column or cell.
    """
    for row in range(len(grid)):
        for col in range(len(grid)):
            # check value is an int
            if grid[row][col] < 1 or type(grid[row][col]) is not type(1):
                return False
            # check value is within 1 through n.
            # for example a 2x2 grid should not have the value 8 in it
            elif grid[row][col] > len(grid):
                return False
        # check the rows
    for row in grid:
        if sorted(list(set(row))) != sorted(row):
            return False
        # check the cols
    cols = []
    for col in range(len(grid)):
        for row in grid:
            cols += [row[col]]
        # set will get unique values, its converted to list so you can compare
        # it's sorted so the comparison is done correctly.
        if sorted(list(set(cols))) != sorted(cols):
            return False
        cols = []
    # if you get past all the false checks return True
    return True
    
def print_grid(grid):
    for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
        row = ""
        for j in range(GRID_SIZE):
            try:
                val = int(grid[i][j])
            except TypeError:
                val = "_"
            except ValueError:
                val = grid[i][j]
            row += "{} ".format(val)
            if j % SUBGRID_SIZE == SUBGRID_SIZE - 1:
                row += " "
        print(row)
        if i % SUBGRID_SIZE == SUBGRID_SIZE - 1:
            print()

def main():
    i = 0
    for grid in GRIDS:
        is_valid = check_sudoku_grid(grid)
        print("This grid {:s}.".format(GRID_NAMES[i]))
        print("Your function should return:  {:s}".format(GRID_RETURNS[i]))
        print("Your function returns:        {}".format(is_valid))
        print_grid(grid)
        i += 1
    
    



 main()
```

Comment: What's not clear here? "'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'" means that in `grid[row][col] < 1` one operand is `None` and the other one is an integer. Clearly, `1` is the integer, so `grid[row][col]` must be `None`.

Comment: Every time you reference some research or another page like "another thread", please provide the link to it. So we can see the same like you.

Comment: ForceBru: Thank you. So what should I do to fix this?

Comment: hc_dev: Thanks, will do. I'm a newbie

Comment: We can't reproduce without the `grids` module. So I asked for a link to "another tread". Please read [ask], there a [example] is required. Otherwise this question would be a duplicate, because it was already answered. Try running with [__python2__: allows comparison with None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708541/python-typeerror-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-nonetype)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605898/sudoku-checker-in-python

Comment: I posted one more answer, with the code from grids module. It was not in the another thread

Comment: Think carefully about the code `if grid[row][col] < 1 or type(grid[row][col]) is not type(1):`. Between `grid[row][col] < 1` and `type(grid[row][col]) is not type(1)`, which do you expect will happen first? Why? What is the intended purpose of checking `type(grid[row][col]) is not type(1)`? If that condition is met, should `grid[row][col] < 1` be tried? Therefore, which should happen first? Do you see a problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
GRID_NAMES = ["is valid", "is valid containing None values", "is valid containing None values (2)", \
              "has an invalid row", "has an invalid column", "has an invalid subgrid"]
GRID_RETURNS = ["True","True","True","False","False","False"]

n = None

a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'
d = 'd'
e = 'e'
f = 'f'
g = 'g'


GRID_VALID =             [[7,3,5,  6,1,4,  8,9,2],
                          [8,4,2,  9,7,3,  5,6,1],
                          [9,6,1,  2,8,5,  3,7,4],
                          
                          [2,8,6,  3,4,9,  1,5,7],
                          [4,1,3,  8,5,7,  9,2,6],
                          [5,7,9,  1,2,6,  4,3,8],
                          
                          [1,5,7,  4,9,2,  6,8,3],
                          [6,9,4,  7,3,8,  2,1,5],
                          [3,2,8,  5,6,1,  7,4,9]
                          ]


GRID_VALID_NONE =        [[7,3,5,  6,1,4,  8,9,2],
                          [8,4,2,  9,7,3,  5,6,1],
                          [9,6,1,  2,8,5,  3,7,4],
                          
                          [2,n,n,  3,4,n,  1,5,7],
                          [4,1,3,  8,5,7,  9,2,6],
                          [5,7,9,  1,2,6,  4,3,8],
                          
                          [1,5,7,  4,9,n,  6,8,3],
                          [6,9,4,  7,3,8,  2,1,5],
                          [n,2,8,  5,6,1,  7,4,9]
                          ]


GRID_VALID_NONE_2 =      [[7,3,5,  6,1,4,  n,9,2],
                          [8,4,2,  9,7,3,  5,6,1],
                          [n,n,1,  2,8,5,  3,7,4],
                          
                          [2,n,n,  3,4,n,  1,5,7],
                          [4,1,3,  8,5,7,  9,2,6],
                          [5,n,9,  1,2,6,  4,3,8],
                          
                          [1,5,7,  4,9,n,  n,8,3],
                          [6,9,4,  7,3,8,  2,1,5],
                          [n,2,8,  5,6,1,  7,4,n]
                          ]


GRID_INVALID_SUBGRID =   [[7,3,5,  6,1,4,  8,9,2],
                          [8,4,2,  9,7,3,  5,6,1],
                          [9,6,1,  2,8,5,  3,7,4],
                          
                          [2,8,6,  3,4,9,  1,5,7],
                          [4,1,3,  n,5,7,  9,2,6],
                          [5,7,9,  1,2,6,  4,3,8],
                          
                          [1,5,7,  4,9,2,  6,8,3],
                          [6,9,4,  7,3,8,  2,1,5],
                          [3,2,n,  8,6,1,  7,4,9]
                          ]


GRID_INVALID_ROW =       [[7,3,5,  6,1,4,  8,9,2],
                          [8,4,2,  9,7,3,  5,6,1],
                          [9,6,1,  2,8,5,  3,7,4],
                          
                          [2,8,6,  3,4,9,  1,5,7],
                          [4,1,3,  8,5,7,  9,2,6],
                          [5,7,9,  1,2,6,  4,3,8],
                          
                          [1,5,7,  4,9,2,  6,8,n],
                          [6,9,4,  7,3,8,  2,1,3],
                          [3,2,8,  5,6,1,  7,4,9]
                          ]


GRID_INVALID_COLUMN =    [[7,3,5,  6,1,4,  8,9,2],
                          [8,4,2,  9,7,3,  5,6,1],
                          [9,6,1,  2,8,5,  3,7,4],
                          
                          [2,8,6,  3,4,9,  1,5,7],
                          [4,1,3,  8,5,7,  9,2,6],
                          [5,7,9,  1,2,6,  4,3,8],
                          
                          [1,5,n,  4,9,2,  6,8,3],
                          [6,9,4,  7,3,8,  2,1,5],
                          [7,2,8,  5,6,1,  n,4,9]
                          ]



GRIDS = [GRID_VALID, GRID_VALID_NONE, GRID_VALID_NONE_2, \
         GRID_INVALID_ROW, GRID_INVALID_COLUMN, GRID_INVALID_SUBGRID]

GRID_SMALL_VALID =               [[1,2, 3,4],
                                  [3,4, 1,2],
                                 
                                  [2,3, 4,1],
                                  [4,1, 2,3]]


GRID_SMALL_VALID_NONE =          [[1,n, 3,4],
                                  [3,4, n,n],
                                 
                                  [2,n, 4,1],
                                  [4,1, n,3]]


GRID_SMALL_VALID_NONE_2 =        [[1,n, 3,4],
                                  [n,n, n,2],
                                 
                                  [2,n, 4,1],
                                  [4,n, 2,3]]


GRID_SMALL_INVALID_ROW =         [[1,2, 3,n],
                                  [2,3, 4,4],
                                 
                                  [3,4, 1,2],
                                  [4,1, 2,3]]


GRID_SMALL_INVALID_COLUMN =      [[1,2, 3,4],
                                  [2,3, 4,1],
                                 
                                  [3,4, n,1],
                                  [4,1, 2,3]]


GRID_SMALL_INVALID_SUBGRID =     [[1,2, 3,4],
                                  [2,3, 4,1],
                                 
                                  [3,4, 1,2],
                                  [4,1, 2,3]]

GRIDS_SMALL = [GRID_SMALL_VALID, GRID_SMALL_VALID_NONE, GRID_SMALL_VALID_NONE_2, \
               GRID_SMALL_INVALID_ROW, GRID_SMALL_INVALID_COLUMN, GRID_SMALL_INVALID_SUBGRID]


GRID_BIG_VALID =                 [[4,a,9,f,  1,7,d,8,  6,e,2,c,  g,5,3,b],
                                  [2,5,3,1,  f,4,b,g,  d,9,8,7,  6,a,c,e],
                                  [e,6,d,c,  3,a,5,2,  g,b,1,4,  8,f,9,7],
                                  [b,7,g,8,  6,e,9,c,  5,3,a,f,  1,2,d,4],
                                  
                                  [8,g,b,4,  d,f,e,9,  2,5,7,3,  c,1,a,6],
                                  [1,e,6,d,  c,8,4,5,  a,g,9,b,  2,3,7,f],
                                  [a,f,5,3,  2,1,6,7,  4,c,e,8,  9,b,g,d],
                                  [c,2,7,9,  b,3,g,a,  f,d,6,1,  4,8,e,5],
                                  
                                  [9,4,1,a,  e,2,3,d,  b,f,c,6,  7,g,5,8],
                                  [5,8,e,g,  7,9,1,6,  3,4,d,a,  b,c,f,2],
                                  [7,3,f,6,  g,b,c,4,  8,2,5,9,  e,d,1,a],
                                  [d,c,2,b,  a,5,8,f,  7,1,g,e,  3,6,4,9],
                                  
                                  [f,9,8,2,  4,c,7,3,  1,a,b,d,  5,e,6,g],
                                  [6,d,c,5,  9,g,f,1,  e,8,4,2,  a,7,b,3],
                                  [g,b,4,7,  8,d,a,e,  c,6,3,5,  f,9,2,1],
                                  [3,1,a,e,  5,6,2,b,  9,7,f,g,  d,4,8,c]
                                  ]



GRID_BIG_VALID_NONE =            [[4,a,9,n,  1,7,d,8,  6,e,n,c,  g,5,3,n],
                                  [n,5,3,1,  f,n,b,g,  d,9,8,7,  6,a,c,e],
                                  [e,6,d,c,  3,a,5,2,  g,b,n,4,  n,f,n,7],
                                  [b,7,n,8,  n,e,9,c,  n,3,a,f,  1,2,d,4],
                                  
                                  [8,g,b,4,  d,f,n,9,  2,5,7,n,  c,1,a,6],
                                  [1,e,n,d,  c,n,4,5,  a,g,n,b,  2,3,7,f],
                                  [a,f,n,3,  2,1,n,7,  n,n,e,8,  9,b,g,n],
                                  [c,2,7,9,  b,3,g,a,  f,d,6,1,  4,n,n,5],
                                  
                                  [9,4,1,a,  e,n,3,d,  b,f,c,6,  7,g,5,8],
                                  [5,n,e,g,  7,9,n,6,  3,4,d,a,  b,n,f,2],
                                  [7,3,f,6,  g,b,c,4,  n,n,5,9,  e,d,n,a],
                                  [n,n,n,b,  a,5,8,f,  7,1,n,e,  3,6,4,9],
                                  
                                  [f,9,8,2,  4,c,7,3,  n,n,b,d,  5,e,6,g],
                                  [6,n,c,5,  9,n,f,1,  e,n,4,2,  a,7,n,3],
                                  [g,b,4,7,  8,d,a,e,  c,6,n,5,  f,9,2,n],
                                  [3,1,n,n,  n,6,2,b,  9,7,f,g,  d,4,8,c]
                                  ]



GRID_BIG_VALID_NONE_2 =          [[4,a,9,f,  1,7,d,n,  6,e,n,n,  g,n,3,b],
                                  [2,5,3,1,  f,4,b,g,  d,n,8,7,  6,a,n,e],
                                  [e,6,d,c,  3,a,n,2,  g,b,1,4,  8,f,9,7],
                                  [b,7,g,n,  n,e,9,c,  5,3,a,n,  n,2,d,4],
                                  
                                  [8,g,b,4,  d,f,e,n,  2,5,7,3,  c,1,a,6],
                                  [1,n,6,d,  n,n,4,n,  a,g,n,b,  2,3,7,f],
                                  [a,f,5,3,  2,1,6,7,  4,c,e,8,  9,b,g,d],
                                  [c,2,7,n,  b,3,g,a,  f,d,6,1,  4,8,e,5],
                                  
                                  [9,4,1,a,  e,2,n,n,  b,f,c,n,  7,g,5,8],
                                  [5,n,e,g,  7,9,n,6,  3,4,d,a,  b,c,f,2],
                                  [7,3,f,6,  g,b,c,4,  8,n,n,n,  e,d,1,a],
                                  [d,c,2,n,  a,n,8,f,  7,1,g,n,  3,6,n,9],
                                  
                                  [f,n,8,2,  4,c,7,3,  1,a,b,d,  n,e,6,n],
                                  [6,d,c,5,  9,g,f,1,  e,8,4,2,  a,7,b,3],
                                  [g,b,n,7,  8,d,a,e,  n,6,n,5,  f,n,2,n],
                                  [n,1,a,e,  n,6,2,b,  9,n,f,g,  d,n,8,c]
                                  ]


GRID_BIG_INVALID_ROW =           [[4,a,9,f,  1,7,d,8,  6,e,2,c,  g,5,3,b],
                                  [2,5,3,1,  f,4,b,g,  d,9,8,7,  6,a,c,e],
                                  [e,6,d,c,  3,a,5,2,  g,b,1,4,  8,f,9,7],
                                  [b,7,g,8,  6,e,9,c,  5,3,a,f,  1,2,d,4],
                                  
                                  [8,g,b,4,  d,f,e,9,  2,5,7,3,  c,1,a,6],
                                  [1,e,6,d,  c,n,4,5,  a,g,9,b,  2,3,7,f],
                                  [a,f,5,3,  2,1,6,7,  4,c,e,8,  9,b,g,d],
                                  [c,2,7,9,  b,3,g,a,  f,d,6,1,  4,8,e,5],
                                  
                                  [9,4,1,a,  e,2,3,d,  b,f,c,6,  7,g,5,8],
                                  [5,8,e,g,  7,9,1,6,  3,4,d,a,  b,c,f,2],
                                  [7,3,f,6,  g,b,c,4,  8,2,5,9,  e,d,1,a],
                                  [d,c,2,b,  a,8,8,f,  7,1,g,e,  3,6,4,9],
                                  
                                  [f,9,8,2,  4,c,7,3,  1,a,b,d,  5,e,6,g],
                                  [6,d,c,5,  9,g,f,1,  e,8,4,2,  a,7,b,3],
                                  [g,b,4,7,  8,d,a,e,  c,6,3,5,  f,9,2,1],
                                  [3,1,a,e,  5,6,2,b,  9,7,f,g,  d,4,8,c]
                                  ]


GRID_BIG_INVALID_COLUMN =        [[4,a,9,f,  1,7,d,8,  6,e,2,c,  g,5,3,b],
                                  [2,5,3,1,  f,4,b,g,  d,9,8,7,  6,a,c,e],
                                  [e,6,d,c,  3,a,5,2,  g,b,1,4,  8,f,9,7],
                                  [b,7,g,8,  6,e,9,c,  5,3,a,f,  1,2,d,4],
                                  
                                  [8,g,b,4,  d,f,e,9,  2,5,7,3,  c,1,a,6],
                                  [1,e,6,d,  c,8,4,5,  a,g,9,b,  2,3,7,f],
                                  [a,f,5,3,  2,1,6,n,  4,c,e,8,  9,b,7,d],
                                  [c,2,7,9,  b,3,g,a,  f,d,6,1,  4,8,e,5],
                                  
                                  [9,4,1,a,  e,2,3,d,  b,f,c,6,  7,g,5,8],
                                  [5,8,e,g,  7,9,1,6,  3,4,d,a,  b,c,f,2],
                                  [7,3,f,6,  g,b,c,4,  8,2,5,9,  e,d,1,a],
                                  [d,c,2,b,  a,5,8,f,  7,1,g,e,  3,6,4,9],
                                  
                                  [f,9,8,2,  4,c,7,3,  1,a,b,d,  5,e,6,g],
                                  [6,d,c,5,  9,g,f,1,  e,8,4,2,  a,7,b,3],
                                  [g,b,4,7,  8,d,a,e,  c,6,3,5,  f,9,2,1],
                                  [3,1,a,e,  5,6,2,b,  9,7,f,g,  d,4,8,c]
                                  ]


GRID_BIG_INVALID_SUBGRID =       [[4,a,9,f,  1,7,d,8,  6,e,2,c,  g,5,3,b],
                                  [2,5,3,1,  f,4,b,g,  d,9,8,7,  6,a,c,e],
                                  [e,6,d,c,  3,a,5,2,  g,b,1,4,  8,f,9,7],
                                  [b,7,g,8,  6,e,9,c,  5,3,a,f,  1,2,d,4],
                                  
                                  [8,g,b,4,  d,f,e,9,  2,5,7,3,  c,1,a,6],
                                  [1,e,6,d,  c,8,4,5,  a,g,9,b,  2,3,7,f],
                                  [a,f,5,3,  2,1,6,7,  4,c,e,8,  9,b,g,d],
                                  [c,2,7,9,  b,3,g,a,  f,d,6,1,  4,8,e,5],
                                  
                                  [9,4,1,a,  e,2,3,d,  b,f,c,6,  7,g,5,8],
                                  [5,8,e,g,  7,9,1,6,  3,n,d,a,  b,c,f,2],
                                  [7,3,f,6,  g,b,c,4,  8,2,5,9,  e,d,1,a],
                                  [d,c,2,b,  a,5,8,f,  7,1,g,e,  3,6,4,9],
                                  
                                  [f,9,8,2,  4,c,7,3,  1,a,b,d,  5,e,6,g],
                                  [6,d,c,5,  9,g,f,1,  e,8,4,2,  a,7,b,3],
                                  [g,b,n,7,  8,d,a,e,  c,4,3,5,  f,9,2,1],
                                  [3,1,a,e,  5,6,2,b,  9,7,f,g,  d,4,8,c]
                                  ]

GRIDS_BIG = [GRID_BIG_VALID, GRID_BIG_VALID_NONE, GRID_BIG_VALID_NONE_2, \
             GRID_BIG_INVALID_ROW, GRID_BIG_INVALID_COLUMN, GRID_BIG_INVALID_SUBGRID]
```